# Chemfig curved arrows in the wrong place [solved]

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

EDIT: I now know what causes the problem.
I failed to mention in this post that I used a header file and the command `\include`.
I thought it would make no difference, and I was wrong.
`\input`, however, works as expected.

---

I'm trying to put curvedarrows in my `chemfig` diagrams but the curved arrows are placed beside the whole scheme instead of on top.

Screenshot of my unfinished reaction scheme:

[image: incomplete reaction scheme]

You can see the curved arrow to the right of the imine molecule, even though I've placed the nodes on the aldehyde.

I tried to draw the aldehyde on its own with the curved arrow too, but it failed just the same.

[image]

And the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \sffamily
    \mhchemoptions{font=sf}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{(-[:-150]R)(=[@{db}:90]@{o}O)-[:-30]H}
    \+
    \chemfig{N(-[:-150]H)(-[:90]H)-[:-30]R}
    \arrow(s1--int){<=>[\ce{H+}]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{(-[:-150]R)(-[:120]HO)(-[:60]N(-[:120]H)-[:0]R)-[:-30]H}}{hemiaminal}
    \+
    \arrow{<=>[\ce{H+}]}
    \chemname{\chemfig{(-[:-150]R)(=[:90]N-[:30]R)-[:-30]H}}{imine}
    \arrow(@s1--s2){<=>[\ce{H+}]}[-90]
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw(db)..controls +(-30:4mm) and +(0:4mm)..(o);}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \sffamily
    \mhchemoptions{font=sf}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{(-[:-150]R)(=[@{db}:90]@{o}O)-[:-30]H}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{\draw(db)..controls +(-30:4mm) and +(0:4mm)..(o);}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `chemfig` manual mentions something about the viewer supporting "picture remembering", but I have no idea what this means.

Thanks for any and all help.

Edited to make the code compilable

Comment: Could it be possible that you just compiled your example document once? If I do so, I get the output you show in your question. Just compile the document again to get the expected output. The documentation explicitly mentions "It is assumed [...] that the compilation is done twice." (See section 13  Representing electron movements, currently on page 21 of the manual.)

Comment: @leandriis I use `latexmk` for auto-compilation, so that shouldn't be an issue. I've also tried with `pdflatex` and even Overleaf as a desperate last-attempt. Recompiling does not fix the issue.