# Why does \include change the output of my document?

Tags: chemfig

This is essentially an expansion on my earlier problem ([Chemfig curved arrows in the wrong place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598302/chemfig-curved-arrows-in-the-wrong-place)) to which I have found a *fix*, but not really a *solution*.

I made a document using a header file which I called in my main document with `\include{chem-hdr}`.
Here is what this file looks like:

```
% LaTeX header file for chemistry

% Packages
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Chemfig settings
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

% Print atoms with a sans-serif font
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{%
    \ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}%
}
```

This would cause any curly arrows to be placed beside my reaction scheme, instead of inside.
In this incomplete reaction scheme, the arrow should be on the aldehyde.

[image: incomplete reaction scheme]

Now with the background covered here's my actual problem:

In my earlier question, I did not specify that I used a header file; instead, I just pasted the header-file code into the MWE.
I assumed this would make no difference.
But it does!

Replacing the `\include{chem-hdr}` line in my preamble with the actual code in the file makes everything work as expected.
Would anyone happen to know why?

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you know [when use \input vs \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)?

Comment: @Fran `\input` works as expected. What do you know! Thanks for the help.

Comment: `\include` does not work in the preamble, really we should make it an error, or at least give a warning

Comment: Forget about `\include` and use `\input`. The former command is ***only*** to be used inside `document` and used to be handy in older times when running LaTeX on big documents might cause excess of coffee-drinking while waiting the run to finish. Nowadays it's rarely needed.